# Given a number N and an array of N strings, sort the strings based on number of vowels in each of the strings in the descending order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I had successfully counted the number of vowels in each element of string array. But i am unable to compare them and the print the array element which has the least number of vowels. Please help me out.
This is the code i had written so far....

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = s.nextInt();
    int vowelcount = 0;
    int maxcount = 0, sum = 0;
    String a[] = new String[N];

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        a[i] = s.next();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        String str = a[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
            if(str.charAt(j) == 'a' || str.charAt(j) == 'e' || str.charAt(j) == 'i'
                    || str.charAt(j) == 'o' || str.charAt(j) == 'u') {
                vowelcount = vowelcount + 1;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(vowelcount);
        vowelcount = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the Arrays and Collections classes allowed?

Comment: Whats the purpose of sorting in descending order and then finding the String with least values?

Comment: Just a comment to the other question that just got deleted on you: it is not really about "opinionated". This community is about programming questions. It is not an advisory board for education or curriculum planning. Thus your question was simply fully off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code.. Please try running the below code

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    int N=s.nextInt();
    int vowelcount=0;
    int maxcount=0,sum=0;
    String a[]=new String[N];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        a[i]=s.next();
    }
    //added
    int minCount = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int minCountIndex = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    //till here
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        String str=a[i];
        for(int j=0;j<str.length();j++){
            if(str.charAt(j)=='a'||str.charAt(j)=='e'||str.charAt(j)=='i'||str.charAt(j)=='o'||str.charAt(j)=='u'){
                vowelcount=vowelcount+1;

            }

        } //Add below lines
        if(vowelcount < minCount) {
            minCount = vovelcount;
            minCountIndex = i;
        } //till here
        System.out.println(vowelcount);
        vowelcount=0;
    }
    System.out.println("String with Minimum Vovels :" + a[minCountIndex]);  // Added this

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom comperator class which suits your needs like this:

```
static class SortDescendingByNumberOfVowels implements Comparator<String> {
    private int getNumberOfVowels(String str) {
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if(str.charAt(i) == 'a' || str.charAt(i) == 'e' || str.charAt(i) == 'i'
                    || str.charAt(i) == 'o' || str.charAt(i) == 'u') {
                counter += 1;
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
        return getNumberOfVowels(str2) - getNumberOfVowels(str1);
    }
}
```

Then use the above comperator to sort the array by using another signature of `Arrays.sort()` which takes as a 2nd parameter the comperator:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
    String a[] = new String[N];

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        a[i] = s.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println("Initial array: " + Arrays.toString(a));

    Arrays.sort(a, new SortDescendingByNumberOfVowels());
    System.out.println("Sorted array : " + Arrays.toString(a));

    System.out.println("Item with less vowels: " + a[N - 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex rather than comparing individual characters to get the vowel count

```
Pattern vowels = Pattern.compile("[aeiou]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
int numberOfVowels = value.length() - vowels.matcher(value).replaceAll("").length();
```

You could also use a stream to do the sorting.

```
Pair fewest = Arrays.stream(values)
        .map(value -> new Pair(value.length() - vowels.matcher(value).replaceAll("").length(), value))
        .sorted((v1, v2) -> Integer.compare(v1.length, v2.length))
        .findFirst().orElse(null);

System.out.println(fewest.value);
```

That relies on having a Pair class which holds the length and value

```
private class Pair {

    int length;
    String value;

    Pair(int length, String value) {
        this.length = length;
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```